# How to mark a Java method as "must use result" for static analysis purposes?

Tags: java, annotations, static-analysis

When using GCC to compile C or C++, you can mark functions with **attribute**((warn_unused_result)) which will cause the compiler to complain if you invoke a function that returns something and then don't assign it to anything.

I have some methods in a Java library I develop that have methods like this - calling them and then throwing away the result is always a bug. I would like API users to be able to identify such bugs via static analysis, such as with FindBugs or IntelliJ inspections.

I am wondering if there is a method annotation that is commonly used to mark methods or functions as "must use result". FindBugs has some special case bug-finders for the standard library, but a general way would be useful.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA by default displays a warning if return result is ignored.

Comment: I don't see that happening. Is there a specific inspection that must be enabled for that?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections/IgnoreResultOfCall.html

Comment: I see, thanks. I suppose I could ship such a list with my project, but an annotation based approach would be cleaner. Perhaps I'll file a feature request with JetBrains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is totally a standard annotation for this, and it is `@CheckReturnValue`.  FindBugs has it; see e.g. [here](http://softdevbuilttolast.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/findbugs-help-create-robust-code-with-the-checkreturnvalue-annotation/).

Guava uses it internally -- e.g. [in the configuration methods for `Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#omitEmptyStrings%28%29) -- from [JSR 305](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.html?is-external=true).

Comment: ErrorProne now has such a check as well: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CheckReturnValue

Comment: Is there a way to get IntelliJ IDEA to automatically add this to any new function created with a return value?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
import javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue;
.
.
.
@CheckReturnValue
```

Some good examples of @CheckReturnValue are available on the Google [error-prone project wiki](https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/wiki/CheckReturnValue). (If you like static analysis tools such as FindBugs, you should definitely check out [error-prone](https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/); it works on the source/AST rather than the bytecode, which makes it complementary to tools such as FindBugs.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this in 2019 or later: annotate the method with `@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.CheckReturnValue` available from `com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations`. [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) is an actively maintained successor to FindBugs.

Comment: What you say about SpotBugs is correct, but you probably mean "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.CheckReturnValue"

Comment: Thanks for flagging this Christophe, I've updated the post with the correct package name.